# Как заблокировать rigidbody.position по осям x и z?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы через код заблокировать `position` у `Rigidbody` только по осям `x` и `z`?

Вот такой код:

```cs
if (freezePositionXZ)
{
    rgbd.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX;
    rgbd.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
}
```

Не работает, и в итоге блокируется только `z`.

Я так понимаю, такая команда позволяет заблокировать только одну ось. Что тогда делать?

Comment: в редакторе у самого компонента Rigidbody есть вкладка "Constraints" и там можно выбрать фриз движения и поворота, без использования кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например [так](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;

    void Start()
    {
        m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
    }
}
```

Вы можете использовать побитовый оператор OR для объединения нескольких ограничений.